# jquery.dataTables.rowGrouping destroy layout with yacdf

Tags: javascript, yadcf

I try to implement **yacdf** with `jquery.dataTables.rowGrouping.js` but everytime that I try to work together something destroy css layout or make conflicts with other .js.

[Live Example of RowGrouping](http://jsfiddle.net/RgKPZ/331/)

This is how I can try implement

```
$(document).ready(function () {

'use strict';

 oTable = $('#example').dataTable({

        "sScrollY": "300px",
        "sScrollX": "90%",
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bStateSave": true  
    }).rowGrouping({
            bExpandableGrouping: true,
            bExpandSingleGroup: false,
            iExpandGroupOffset: -1,
            asExpandedGroups: [""]
        });

        GridRowCount();
    });
```

My clean table example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/26/

Comment: yacdf does not support integration with the rowGrouping and there wont be such integration in the future

Comment: i find now a solution for yacdf+rowGrouping http://nathan4000.altervista.org/yacdf3/row_group_datatables/fiddle.jshell.net/RgKPZ/331/show/light/example7.html

Comment: oki, the *Hayao Miyazaki, Studio Ghibli* is good.